# Using Firebase to create a collaborative TableView list

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I got this idea to create something quite simple as an exercise in Firebase, I want to create a simple App with a couple of views: A "Homepage" / Splash screen which navigates to a couple of different views:

- A "friends" list where the user can add other users and monitor their online / offline status as well as send them an invite to a selected group
- An "invites" screen monitoring incoming invites
- A "groups" list where the user can create, delete and select group(s)
- And finally a collaborative list shared between members of the selected group.

A quick use-case:

> 1. A user "User1" opens the app and creates a group "TestGroup" and click it to select it as the active group
> 2. The user then heads to the friends screen, here they add a friends "User2" and click their name in the list, a popup arrears asking them to confirm whether they want to invite "User2" to join the active group "TestGroup"
> 3. "User2" finds an invite on his "invites" screen which he click to accept
> 4. Now "User1" and "User2" can both read and write to the aforementioned collaborative TableView list which changes depending on which "group" is active / selected.

Is this something that's possible? I've gone through a few tutorials regarding basic Firebase setup like this: https://www.raywenderlich.com/187417/firebase-tutorial-getting-started-3 which suit my needs quite well, but I don't know where to get started about the "collaborative" list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Structure can be like this:

```
-MembersForGroups  //here you have the groups and the members that are on each group, so when the user chooses a group the members are easily displayed
  --Group1ID
    ---member1ID:true  //when the user creates a group, the groupID is create and their user id is automatially added as member
    ---member2ID:true

-Colabsheets //here you have all the colab sheets with each group containing the posts that users have made.
  --Group1ID // Give the sheet the same ID as the group so when you choose a group you can easily load the colab sheet.
    ---Post1
            senderid:""
            message:""
            timestamp:""
    ---Post2 ....
```

Comment: Very interesting, thanks! I don't have a very intuitive understanding of Firebase yet so I'm not quite sure how to implement what you mentioned but I'll try figuring it out as I go, thanks a lot.

Comment: I added some comments on my answers to make it a bit clearer, if you have no idea yet about Firebase, read the documentation,practise and everything will make sense. If my answer helps you please consider accepting/upvoting it.

Comment: Thanks! I already upvoted it but since I have less than 15 rep my votes don't show up publicly ("Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.")

Comment: Yes until you have 15 rep you can only accept answers(the checkmark next to every answer on your questions. Good luck with your project.